# Slice assignment with equal bounds

Tags: python, slice

If the bounds are equal, then the slicing interval is empty, so assigning to it should assign to nothing, and the list should remain unmodified, right?

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> l[1:1]
[]   # (as expected)
>>> l[1:1] = [4]
>>> l
[0, 4, 1, 2, 3]
# why did 4 get in there?
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Slice assignment to an empty slicing interval acts as insertion of a sublist.

#### My (possibly wrong!) explanation:

Slice assignment is the replacement of a sublist. Sublist replacement is sublist deletion followed by sublist insertion. If the sublist to be replaced is empty, then its deletion has no effect, so its replacement with another sublist acts like an insertion.

#### Other kinds of empty slicing intervals

They seem to work the same:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3]

# bounds in the "wrong" order:

>>> l[1:0]
[]
>>> l[1:0] = [4]
>>> l
[0, 4, 1, 2, 3]

# bounds beyond the size of the list:

>>> l[20:100]
[]
>>> l[20:100] = [5]
>>> l
[0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Okay, just tested and this is **NOT CORRECT IN GENERAL**. It is something that only happens with iterable objects. You're making assumptions based on the behavior of some little piece of code, you should check whether or not this is specified to be the intended usage by the language.

Comment: You should at least better clarify that this only works with iterable objects on the right side as it seems to be treated as sublist insertion (when it really is something different).

Comment: Before posting my answer, I tried to check the [Python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) but did not find mentions of this behavior.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Is this better?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli No TypeError with this code on my version of Python (3.7.3). What is your issue with my code? [4] is an iterable since it is a list. Besides, it should work with tuples too on the right side, or any iterable, not just lists.

Comment: oh, sorry about that! Totally missed the brackets. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

> assign to nothing, and the list should remain unmodified

No, it's replacing nothing with the value. Before, there was nothing between `l[1]` and `l[1]`, and now there's `E`. You can also try

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
l[1:3]='E'
```

This will result in `l` being `['a', 'E', 'd']`, not `['a', 'E', 'E', 'd']`: what slice you name is replaced by the value. If you do

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
l[1:2]=['E','F','G']
```

That will result in `l` being `['a', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'c', 'd']`.

Comment: A more appropriate way to say this is that it is inserting an iterable in the list overwriting the provided slice. That is, *in place* of the provided slice.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli This is precisely what my answer was attempting to say.

Comment: @Fornost you should word it better though, you seem to be hovering around the point a little bit too much. For example you don't know for sure if sublist replacement is sublist deletion followed by sublist insertion, it *could* be.